# laravel error 403 when CP is in url how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-8, http-status-code-403

I got error 403 when in the url, CP (with a space after) is write.

I use laravel 8.

Exemple : /addFile/CP ABER

if "CP " is here, i got error 403.

How can i fix it ? Thanks

Comment: you cant have spaces in your URL you should change to /CP_ABER or you need to urlencode "CP ABER"

Answer (score 1):

Spaces is not allowed in url. You need to encode it. When you encode it spaces will converted to `%20`. so your url will look like `/addFile/CP%20ABER`.